# string values need to be replaced in quotes in oracle

Tags: string, single-quotes

[image]

I have a column buyer with two values as (OTHER,ANGIE WAN), need to be in quotes as 'OTHER','ANGIE WAN'.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

perhaps replace commas with ','

```
update my_table set buyer '''' || replace(buyer, ',', ''',''') || ''''
```